# Git log rev range master gives different results between master and branch

Tags: git, git-log

I'm on a release branch, where I apply cherry-picked commits from *master* (main development).

I wanted to check whether some old commits have already been copied over so I started using `git log` and `grep` to find one of the commit hashes.

When on a branch I usually compare latest commits there with respect to *master* with:

```
git log --oneline -20
```

and

```
git log --oneline -20 master
```

But now that I wanted to check a range of commits, after some trials and errors I ended up using:

```
git log --oneline <myhash>~..HEAD master
```

Which, when *master* is checked out, gives the expected results - the list of commits from `<myhash>` (inclusive) to the latest one of master.

If ran when I'm on a different branch, though, that same command yields different results (actually it seems to give all the commits from the beginning of the branch up to the latest): why?

Comment: `HEAD` is resolved to `master` when `master` is checked out. When on `master`, just use `git log --oneline <myhash>~..` but from anywhere else you can do `git log --oneline <myhash>~..master`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see all commits on a branch starting from a specific other commit, use the following:

```
git log --oneline start..branch
```

Where `start` is the starting commit and `branch` is the final commit. Git will show all commits reachable from `branch` and exclude those reachable from `start` (same behavior is achieved by: `git log ^start branch`, i.e. "not start" and "branch")

When you do `start..HEAD master` you will get all commits between start and the current commit/branch *AND* all commits reachable from `master`. In that case you are actually specifying 3 commits: `^start`, `HEAD`, and `master`. Git will then traverse the graph to give you the result: all commits reachable from `HEAD` (the current commit/branch), all commits reachable from `master`, but exclude all commits reachable from `start`

Comment: I see, I was misusing `HEAD` then, and was confused about `master` acting differently with the same command but together with different parameters.